# Debye model density of states in one dimension

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

I am trying to obtain the density of states of the Debye model in one dimension.
I know that the correct expression is
$$\frac{L}{\pi c_s}$$
where $c_s$ is the speed of sound in the material.
However, when I try to work it outmyself, I get
$$\sum_k{f(c_s|k|)} \rightarrow \frac{L}{2\pi}\int{f(c_s|k|)~dk} \, .$$
Using $\omega=c_s|k|$ we get
$$dk=\frac{d\omega}{c_s}$$
which gives
$$\rightarrow\frac{L}{2\pi{c_s}} \int{f(\omega) \, d\omega} \, .$$
Therefore, the density of states is
$$\frac{L}{2\pi c_s} \, .$$
I know I need to multiply by two.
Why?
Is it like with the 2 transverse one longitudinal modes of vibration?
I have done a lot of searching for help on page 7 of [some online notes (pdf)](http://phy.ntnu.edu.tw/~changmc/Teach/SS/SS_note/chap05.pdf) where they show the calculation just not why the 2 is placed in front.

I have also found on Wikipedia that

> "The 1, 2 and 3-dimensional density of wave vector states for a line, disk, or sphere are explicitly written as
>   \begin{align}
> N_1(k) =& 2 \\
> N_2(k) =& 2\pi{k} \\
> N_3(k) =& 4\pi{k^2}
> \end{align}

I understand the last two which is recognizing the independence on the direction and using spherical integration (because the density of states in two and three dimensions would have $dk^N$ for the integration).
It's the last one I don't understand.

Comment: The two comes into play based on whether or not you are using periodic boundary conditions for the chain of atoms. See here https://nanohub.org/resources/1188/download/2006.08.11-fisher.pdf

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First response was a misunderstanding of the question I apologise for this.

The reason for the introduction of the factor of 2 is to account for the 2 independent directions along the 1-D line, i.e acounts for right and left moving waves

Comment: The OP is referring to density of states for phonon modes.

Comment: I believe the answer should be correct now after my latest edit.

Comment: I considered it a few times but I am not entirely sure about it. My major reason is that $w=c_s|k|$, but considering it now to include the negative direction I could multiply by two (before is only half the number of states). Can someone confirm this sort of thinking?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have two $\omega$ for each $\vert \vec{k} \vert$, $\vec{k}$ ''to the left'' and ''to the right''. You can also see this as the boundary of an one-dimensional disk. Looking at $\vert \vec{r} - \vec{r}_{0} \vert < R$ as a ball in one dimension, the boundary are two points, just as boundary in two dimensional space would be $2\pi R$ and so on.